# Geoserver proxy extention

Tags: geoserver

i got geoserver 2.1.2 and when i wanna add the jar file ( for proxy extention for geoserver) 
in the desired file "geoserver 2.1.2/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib" and clicked to "Proxy Admin Page" in the GeoServer Web UI i got this error :

HTTP ERROR: 500

class org.geoserver.web.proxy.HostnameProvider overrides final method model.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/wicket/model/IModel;
RequestURI=/geoserver/web/;jsessionid=p5z1wj01ackj

Caused by:

java.lang.VerifyError: class org.geoserver.web.proxy.HostnameProvider overrides final method model.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/wicket/model/IModel;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    .

Im looking forward this error already one week and i cannot find any suggestions or solutions to handle this error :s

Need HELP please !!

Comment: may be useful for you http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+Proxy+Extension

Comment: try upgrading to 2.3 (2.1.2 is very old)